# the parking inspector was sticking this on my windshield

Tags: tense

**Man**: What is it?

**Woman**: What does it look like? It's a ticket. I got a ticket.
Well, read it.

**Man**: Overtime parking from 10 a.m. to 12:15 p.m. Ah, I don't understand.

**Woman**: Well, you're not allowed to park on the street for more than 2 hours. It's against the law.

**Man**: Well, did you park for more than 2 hours?

**Woman**: No. That's the whole point. I didn't park my car until
11 a.m. But when I got back, **the parking inspector was sticking this on my
windshield**.

**Man**: Why?

**Woman**: He accuses me of parking in excess of 2 hours.

---

"the parking inspector **was sticking** this on my windshield" Which tense is this sentence in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the past continuous tense.  Here it is used for placing a short action, "when I got back," into a longer background action, "...the parking inspector was sticking this on my windshield."

From a book on English grammar that I have written:

> For interrupted action in the past, the quick action that
> interrupted the more prolonged action will be in the simple past, and the
> longer action will be in the past continuous tense.  The short action
> may or may not stop the longer action. **When, as,** and **while** are
> often used to link the two clauses.  If the sentence begins with a
> **when, as,** or **while** clause, we often use a comma to separate the clauses.

Note these:

> I saw him when he was exercising in the park.
> As he was exercising in the park, he fell.
> While he was exercising in the park, she saw him.
> We were checking in at the airport when I heard the explosion.
> I was driving to the airport when he called me.
> When I was driving to the airport, I saw a deer.

Answer (score 1):

The Past continuous tense. It uses the past tense of the verb *be* and the *–ing* form of a verb.

It's explained [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/past-continuous).